# Upgrading accelerate while using Trainer class

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-trainer

I am facing an issue whilst using Trainer class with Pytorch on Google Colab as it demands accelarate>=0.21.0 even though I have updated all the requirements, is there any alternative to it?

"Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.21.0`: Please run `pip install transformers[torch]` or `pip install accelerate -U`".
I have tried both the above suggestions but none worked. I don't know what am I doing wrong or how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

> I’m getting the same error in the colab notebook for the NLP Course: Lesson 3 - Fine-tuning model with the Trainer API. In order to get around it you can:
>
> 1. Run pip install accelerate -U in a cell
> 2. In the top menu click Runtime → Restart Runtime
> 3. Do not rerun any cells with !pip install in them
> 4. Rerun all the other code cells and you should be good to go!

> On a side note, be sure to turn on a GPU for this notebook by clicking Edit → Notebook Settings → GPU type - from the top menu. This was the next thing that got me : )

Source: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/trainingargument-does-not-work-on-colab/43372/6